# Find out which condition breaks a logical and expression

Tags: python, boolean-expression

I want to find an elegant way to get the component of the logical `and` expression below that is responsible if the `if` block is *not* being executed.

```
if test1(value) and test2(value) and test3(value):
   print 'Yeeaah'
else:
   print 'Oh, no!', 'Who is the first function that return false?'
```

In case the `else` block is entered, how do I find out whether `test1`, `test2` or `test3` is responsible by returning the first falsy value?

Salvo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `next` and a generator expression:

```
breaker = next((test.__name__ for test in (test1, test2, test3) if not test(value)), None)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def test1(value): return True
>>> def test2(value): return False
>>> def test3(value): return True
>>> value = '_' # irrelevant for this demo
>>>
>>> tests = (test1, test2, test3)
>>> breaker = next((test.__name__ for test in tests if not test(value)), None)
>>> breaker
'test2'
>>> if not breaker:
...:    print('Yeeaah')
...:else:
...:    print('Oh no!')
...:    
Oh no!
```

Note that `test3` is never called in this code.

(Super corner case: use `if breaker is not None` over `if not breaker` if for reasons I cannot fathom pranksters reassigned the function's `__name__` attribute to `''`.)

**~edit~**

In case you want to know whether the first, second, or n'th test returned something *falsy*, you can use a similar generator expression with `enumerate`.

```
>>> breaker = next((i for i, test in enumerate(tests, 1) if not test(value)), None)
>>> breaker
2
```

If you want to count from zero, use `enumerate(tests)` and check `if breaker is not None` for entering the `if` block (because `0` is *falsy* like `None`).

Comment: This seems to me the most pythonic answer, and most easily generalized

Answer (score 4):

We could store that test values in list and then check if they all are True and if not print index of first value that is False.

```
def test1(x):
    return True
def test2(x):
    return False
def test3(x):
    return True

value = 'a'
statements = [test1(value), test2(value), test3(value)]

if all(statements):
   print('Yeeaah')
else:
   print('Oh, no! Function that first return False is {}'.format(statements.index(False)))
```

Output:

```
Oh, no! Function that first return False is 1
```

Comment: Maybe at least some text would benefit your answer

Comment: Note that this does evaluate all the tests, while the chained `and` operations are lazy and short circuit. So in theory if the tests have side effects, this code is not strictly equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Split it three-ways:

Using python3 syntax:

```
b1 = test1(value)
b2 = test2(value)
b3 = test3(value)

if b1 and b2 and b3:
    print("Yeah")
else:
    print("Nope! 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}".format(b1, b2, b3))
```